# Асинхронность в браузере

Tags: браузер, асинхронность

В браузере для одной вкладки доступен только один поток, при выполнении запросов на сервер, ожидание ответа от сервера выполняют другие потоки, Получается что он не однопоточный если сделаю одновременно 10 запросов, 10 потоков будут слушать ответ от сервера и при получении ответа основной поток будет уведомлен об этом, Получается что все равно 11 потоков обслуживают вкладку?

Comment: Многопоточность и асинхронность — никак не связанные друг с другом понятия. В одном потоке могут выполняться (не одновременно, но по очереди) несколько io-bound задач, в вашем случае — 10 задач по получению ответа от сервера.

Comment: Вообще, ожидание ответа от сервера не требует потоков. Поток может заниматься любыми делами, просто периодически спрашивая у операционной системы, а не пришёл ли случайно ответ от сервера (select, epoll и т. п.). Сделайте хоть миллион запросов — ожидать ответов от всех них может один-единственный поток. Когда ответ придёт, поток займется обработкой ответа, а потом снова вернётся к ожиданию остальных 999999 ответов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, но необязательно и вряд ли.

В конечном счёте, сколько бы запросов вы ни выполняли со страницы, весь связанный с ними обмен данных идёт через один-единственный канал где-то на низких уровнях системы. По кусочкам. Кусочек ответа на один запрос, кусочек ответа на другой, потом очередной кусочек ответа на первый, потом вдруг кусочек ответа на третий...

Чтобы эффективно распределять такой поток данных по получателям, одного потока выполнения на уровне ОС вполне достаточно.

Comment: а если я скачиваю в браузере 10 файлов одновременно потом еще в торенте файлов 10 скачивается и раздается, даже в этом случае будет работать только один поток?

Comment: @JNat если через один сетевой адаптер, то да, канал данных на все эти передачи будет один.